# Significance of the placement of next() in Node middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have middleware that pulls regions from a postgres database (using the pg package).  Didn't have any issues pulling the data, but every time I tried loading the page, I noticed that the logs in my last middleware to load the view never printed, and I would get this error in my view: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

I figured out that the solution was to move the next() to immediately inside of the query instead of outside of it, but I don't understand why this changed anything.

```
exports.getRegions = async (req, res, next) => {
    var queryStr = 'select distinct region from info order by region asc;'
    const client = await pool.connect()

    client.query(queryStr, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack)
        } else {
            res.locals.regions = results.rows
            next()          
        }
    })
//WHERE next() ORIGINALLY WAS PLACED -- this caused an undefined error 

}
```

I don't understand why the placement of the next() changes whether it's called or not because it's in the scope of the function?  Or why my res.locals variable kept saying it was undefined because of it

Comment: Because your query is asynchronous and your telling it to go to the next middleware before it's completed.  So `res.locals.regions` will not yet been assigned.  Basically `next` tells your middleware I'm done here, now go to the `next` one.

Comment: `next()` should be at the end of each of your function's code paths. Note that the function you show has a code path that ends without ever hitting `next()` (because if there's an error in .query, the call chain never continues) so this is not a good function: that `next()` needs to after the `}`, not before, with `err` as its argument so that express can fall through to the error handling middleware.

Comment: See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html for the overly-complete explanation

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  That link doesn't really say the best way to handle this, all the OP needs is  `console.log(err.stack); next(err);`  That link has how to create an error handling middleware instead.  This link is more appropriate -> https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- didn't realize that I even needed a next in the error handling part!  thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Keith oooo.  im trying to get better with async now, so i totally missed that aspect of it in debugging!  thank you!!